# Copy parent query into another variable and add more conditions to it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I declared a variable which is basically a select query, and I need to copy this parent variable into another one, and then add some where conditions to this copied variable. The thing is that my where conditions are being applied to the first variable and not the one I'd like to.

```
//main query
$query = News::select('news.id','news.created_at','news.idCategory')->with('newsTranslations');

if ($request->has('categories')) {
    $query = $query->whereIn('news.idCategory', $input['categories']);
}

if ($request->has('jobCategories')) {
    $query = $query->join('jobCategories_News','news.id','=','jobCategories_News.idNews')
    ->whereIn('jobCategories_News.idjobCategories', $input['jobCategories']);
}
$chartquery = $query; // copy of parent query variable
$chartquery= $chartquery->leftJoin('newsInteractions','news.id','=','newsInteractions.idNews');

//subqueries (applied to $query instead of $chartquery)
$vis_like = $chartquery->where('liked','=',1)->where('visualizationDate','!=', NULL)->count();
$no_vis_like= $chartquery->where('liked','=',1)->where('visualizationDate','=', NULL)->count();
$dislike = $chartquery->where('liked','=',0)->count();
$vis_no_like= $chartquery->where('liked','=',NULL)->where('visualizationDate','!=', NULL)->count();
```

Comment: I think that you have clone the object: $chartquery = clone($query);

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
  $query = News::select('news.id','news.created_at','news.idCategory')- >with('newsTranslations');

    if ($request->has('categories')) {
        $query = $query->whereIn('news.idCategory', $input['categories']);
    }

    if ($request->has('jobCategories')) {
        $query = $query->join('jobCategories_News','news.id','=','jobCategories_News.idNews')
        ->whereIn('jobCategories_News.idjobCategories', $input['jobCategories']);
    }

    $chartquery = clone $query;
    $chartquery= $chartquery->leftJoin('newsInteractions','news.id','=','newsInteractions.idNews');

    $vis_like = clone $query;
    $vis_like = $vis_like->where('liked','=',1)->where('visualizationDate','!=', NULL)->count();
```

Thanks u guys!